# Editable gridview based on list

Tags: asp.net, list, gridview

Is it possible to create a gridview based on a list? I have the following list:

```
ID = 1
Name = John
Zip = 33141
ID = 2
Name = Tim
Zip = 33139
```

I want to be able to create an editable gridview with this list

When i bind it to the grid view, it seems to put everyting in one column, and i can't figure out how to get it to seperate it into different columns

Here is my code for setting the `DataSource` of the `GridView`:

```
DataTable table = ConvertListToDataTable(personList); 
GridView1.DataSource = table; 
GridView1.DataBind(); 

static DataTable ConvertListToDataTable(List<string> list) 
{ 
    // New table. 
    DataTable table = new DataTable(); 

    // Get max columns. 
    int columns = 7; 

    // Add columns. 
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) 
    { 
        table.Columns.Add(); 
    } 

    // Add rows. 
    foreach (var rd in list) 
    { 
        table.Rows.Add(rd); 
    } 

    return table; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
    private class Person
    {
        int m_iID;
        string m_sName;
        string m_sZip;

        public int ID { get { return m_iID; } }
        public string Name { get { return m_sName; } }
        public string Zip { get { return m_sZip; } }

        public Person(int iID, string sName, string sZip)
        {
            m_iID = iID;
            m_sName = sName;
            m_sZip = sZip;
        }
    }

    private List<Person> m_People;

    private void ConvertListToDataTable(List<Person> People)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        DataColumn col1 = new DataColumn("ID");
        DataColumn col2 = new DataColumn("Name");
        DataColumn col3 = new DataColumn("Zip");

        col1.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        col2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        col3.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");

        table.Columns.Add(col1);
        table.Columns.Add(col2);
        table.Columns.Add(col3);


        foreach (Person person in People)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            row[col1] = person.ID;
            row[col2] = person.Name;
            row[col3] = person.Zip;

            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }            

        GridView1.DataSource = table;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: How would i create the Person class in a seperate class file and be able to use it in my code behind for the form?

Comment: Add new item -> Code -> Class. Then create/move the Person class into it. Inside the forms code behind file, use the class file with "Using ProjectNamespace.Folder". For instance, if your class file is in your App_Code folder: Using ProjectNamespace.App_Code; . Make sure to select this answer if it answers your question!

Comment: Hey is it possible to do the following?

I created a class file with person, and now i wanted to be able to take a list like this:

testList
========================
ID = 1
Name = john
Zip = 33141
ID = 2
Name = tim
Zip = 33139

I don't know if it is correct to do this, but

Person prs = new Person();
List<Person> m_persons;

foreach(string txt in testList)
{
// I wanted to do something like this, so i can dynamically set each variable by just passing an existing list like this to that object
// and have dynamically set the variable
prs.[txt] = txt;

}

Comment: Sorry, I do not really understand what you are trying to do. Create a new question and link it here. Or edit the above question to have an example of what you are trying to accomplish.